# Laravel-vue html2canvas cors error when converting html to image

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert the html to image using html2canvas in laravel-vue.

The image is already showing in html but when it try to convert into image will create new element then request again in the image link. How to fix this error have try to fix it in laravel cors its not working since this link is not my server. in vue how to do it? Btw this monolith.

Any advice maybe alternative way to do it.

HTML

```html
<div id="dwn">
  <img class="pt-2 my-2 mx-md-0" :src="`https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png`" alt="">
</div>
```

html2canvas

```js
methods: {
    convertToImage() {
        const element = document.getElementById('dwn');
        html2canvas(element, { 
            useCORS : true,
            allowTaint : true,
            dpi : 500,
            foreignObjectRendering: false,
            logging: true,
        }).then((canvas) => {
            const image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href =  image;
            link.download = 'generated-Image.png';
            link.click();
        });
    },
},
```

Cors Error

```
Access to image at 'https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png' 
   from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' 
   has been blocked by CORS policy: 
   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```